# Simple Countdown Application C# Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have been working on a simple countdown timer in C# using Visual Studio to be used to close an application after a period of time.

However, right now all I have running is the countdown display on a Windows form.

My issue is when stepping through each piece, the logic appears to be sound, the seconds count down, the minutes count off seconds reach 0, etc.

However, the issue is after one second, the Textbox to display the remaining time changes from "1 minute 59 seconds remaining" to "1 minute and 1 seconds remaining," and appears to just hang there, regardless of how long I let the application run.

Am I missing something in my logic here?

Thank you all in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    int i_minutes = 1;
    int i_seconds = 59;


    public TestTimer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb_TimeRemaining.Text = String.Format("{0} minutes {1} seconds remaining", i_minutes.ToString(), i_seconds.ToString());
        timer1.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //while the timer ticks
        while (i_seconds != 0 && i_minutes != 0)
        {
            //if the seconds reaches 0, subtract a minute
            if(i_seconds == 0)
            {
                i_minutes = i_minutes - 1;

                //if the minutes are still not below 0, reset the seconds to 59
                if (i_minutes >= 0)
                {
                    i_seconds = 59;
                }
            }

            //add a zero to seconds if its below 10
            //so it displays such as 09, 08, etc
            if (i_seconds < 10 && i_minutes != 0)
            {
                lb_TimeRemaining.Text = String.Format("{0} minutes 0{1} seconds remaining", i_minutes, i_seconds);
            }

            //if seconds are above 10,  but minutes below 0, display as 0 minutes and seconds
            else if (i_minutes < 0)
            {
                lb_TimeRemaining.Text = String.Format("0 minutes {1} seconds remaining", i_minutes, i_seconds);
            }

            //if the minutes are above 0, and seconds above 10, display as such
            else
            {
                lb_TimeRemaining.Text = String.Format("{0} minutes {1} seconds remaining", i_minutes, i_seconds);
            }

            i_seconds = i_seconds - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change you while in a if and sets the timer to have an interval of exactly 1000 milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your error and the problem is exactly explained in your comment

```
//while the timer ticks
while (i_seconds != 0 && i_minutes != 0)
```

No, this doesn't allow the timer to tick again because you enter in a loop that exits only after one of your variable reaches zero.

This doesn't happen because a new tick event is raised but happens internally the loop according to your calculations. The time required is probably a lot lower than a second. Finally you reach the end of the event handler and the label is updated with the last value calculated in the while loop.

You should allow the Tick event to end and release the control to your OS that will be able to update the label

Change that line to

```
if (i_seconds != 0 && i_minutes != 0)
{
    ....
}
```

Now your code exits the event handler, the OS updates the label and a new Tick event will be raised according to the value set in the the Interval property

Comment: Oh wow...thank you. A 'while' loop just seemed to make the most sense in my head. But you're right, the tick would never fire. Appreciate it, @Steve.